# How to use client secret having special characters in groovy

Tags: groovy, microsoft-graph-api, special-characters, soapui, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to run Microsoft graph API to generate token. This is working fine in postman but failed in SoapUI. I think client secret has special characters which are causing the issue.

**client secret:**

```
osi5oX-:?0A3YiG4aCpZ.Y[+PW51pZVY
```

**API URL (POST) :**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Body:**

```
client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=osi5oX-:?0A3YiG4aCpZ.Y[+PW51pZVY&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Error:**

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 32b5bf83-f908-4b4e-9fe6-5b05fd949e00\r\nCorrelation ID: b9b7ce92-f5d1-41d1-8d92-eed8a6a5470b\r\nTimestamp: 2020-05-07 17:27:08Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2020-05-07 17:27:08Z","trace_id":"32b5bf83-f908-4b4e-9fe6-5b05fd949e00","correlation_id":"b9b7ce92-f5d1-41d1-8d92-eed8a6a5470b","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"}
```

Comment: you have to use urlencoding for values for this kind of body https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Simply your client secret is incorrect

Comment: Has urlencoding solving your issue?

Comment: Still trying...will update if works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use secret after encoding and it works.

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
String url = "osi5oX-:?0A3YiG4aCpZ.Y[+PW51pZVY"
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8" );
println(encodedUrl)​
```